# How to toggle show and hide LeftView/RightView of UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Currently, I set my textfield with LeftView ( icon ) but I want to toggle show it when click some button.

[image: example image]

My code.

```
let imageIconLeftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage())
view.addSubview(imageIconLeftView)
self.inputTextField.leftView = view
self.inputTextField.leftViewMode = .always
```

I have a button for toggle it but I have no idea to do this.

```
func hideIcon() {
    /// code for hide textfield's leftView
}
```

Can someone suggest some idea about it?.

Comment: your question is not clear, please add some info.

Comment: Define textfield class here

Comment: I already updated my question @Anbu.Karthik. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Put them in `StackView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `hideIcon` method, try `self.inputTextField.leftView = nil` and don't forget to call your `hideIcon` method.